# How to go from VBA Scripting Dictionary to Table Object

Tags: excel, vba

I am heavily using scripting dictionaries in one of my VBA classes and the end goal is to output all the dictionary information into a table. Is there any quick way to have a single row table created from the dictionary?

My previous attempts have all been to try outputting the dictionary data into a pre-made empty table but I feel like there must be a way to create the table as I unload the dictionary.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code.  Seems like the easiest approach would be to create a 2-D array, populate it from your dictionary, then drop it on the worksheet and format the range as a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no method that creates a `Table` from a `Dictionary` as far as I'm aware. So you'd need to convert the dictionary items to some other data container. Tim Williams' suggestion of the variant array would be the easiest way to do it.

I don't want to be the kill-joy here, but are `Dictionaries` the right choice for you? If you're going to create lists that will ultimately populate a `Table`, then you might consider using a `Recordset` as your 'list' object instead of a `Dictionary`. `Tables` have been designed to work with `Recordsets` so many of the coding tasks have been simplified for you. For example, you'd only need one line of code to create and populate the `Table`. If you can be bothered to amend all of your dictionaries, then this might be a route for you to go.

The code below shows you how it can work. I've included a brief function that converts a `Dictionary` to a one row `Recordset`, but I'd look at using `Recordsets` throughout.

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim d As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim rng As Range

    'Some dummy dictionary data
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")
    With d
        .Add "Hdr " & .Count, "Dummy Item #1"
        .Add "Hdr " & .Count, "Dummy Item #2"
        .Add "Hdr " & .Count, "Dummy Item #3"
        .Add "Hdr " & .Count, "Dummy Item #4"
    End With

    'Convert dictionary to recordset.
    'Note: not needed if you re-wrote your code
    'to have your lists as recordsets.
    Set rs = DicToRs(d)

    'Set destination range for table.
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    'Create the table.
    Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, rs, , , rng).Refresh

    'Remember to close the recordset.
    rs.Close

End Sub
Private Function DicToRs(d As Object) As Object
    Const adVarChar As Long = 200
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim v As Variant

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With rs
        For Each v In d.Keys
            .Fields.Append CStr(v), adVarChar, 255
        Next
        .Open
        .AddNew
        For Each v In d.Keys
            .Fields(CStr(v)) = d(v)
        Next
        .Update
    End With

    Set DicToRs = rs


End Function
```